# Mac OS X python 'import vigra' error

Tags: python, macos

I want to use [vigra](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/vigra/) under Mac OS X 10.6.4. So I installed all dependencies with Macpotrs. 
Everything compiled and I could install vigra too. But when I try to import vigra, then I get a 'Segmentation fault'. Do someone know how to solve this problem?
Here the Mac OS X error report:

> Process:         Python [784] Path:
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Identifier:      Python Version:
>   ??? (???) Code Type:       X86-64
>   (Native) Parent Process:  bash [779]
>
> Date/Time:       2010-10-02
>   14:21:08.522 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569) Report
>   Version:  6
>
> Interval Since Last Report:
>   3444718 sec Crashes Since Last Report:
>   91 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report: 
>   12 Anonymous UUID:
>   D1732CEB-3906-4947-832C-99C1C260905E
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
>   0x0000000000000000 Crashed Thread:  0 
>   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread 0   ???
>     000000000000000000 0 + 0 1
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001010977f2 PyImport_Import +
>   139 2   org.python.python
>     0x000000010109799f
>   PyImport_ImportModule + 40 3
>   vigranumpycore.so
>     0x0000000100557b33
>   init_module_vigranumpycore() + 19 4
>   libboost_python-mt.dylib
>     0x000000010071f511
>   boost::python::handle_exception_impl(boost::function0)
>   + 273 5   libboost_python-mt.dylib        0x0000000100720676 bool
>   boost::python::handle_exception(void (*)()) + 54 6
>   libboost_python-mt.dylib
>     0x000000010072041b
>   boost::python::detail::init_module(char
>   const*, void (*)()) + 91 7
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d3911
>   _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 177 8   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d1bcf import_submodule +
>   383 9   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d20ea load_next + 234 10
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d23fb
>   PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 363 11 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000af973 builtin_**import**
>   + 131 12  org.python.python               0x000000010000b902 PyObject_Call + 98
>   13  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000b0bb7
>   PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 14 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000b4e7e PyEval_EvalFrameEx
>   + 12622 15  org.python.python                 0x00000001000b9af5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx
>   + 2197 16  org.python.python              0x00000001000b9c16 PyEval_EvalCode +
>   54 17  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000ceac0
>   PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 208 18 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000cfd22 load_source_module
>   + 722 19  org.python.python               0x00000001000d12df load_package + 463
>   20  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d1bcf import_submodule +
>   383 21  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d20ea load_next + 234 22
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000d23fb
>   PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 363 23 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000af973 builtin_**import**
>   + 131 24  org.python.python               0x000000010000b902 PyObject_Call + 98
>   25  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000b0bb7
>   PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 26 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000b4e7e PyEval_EvalFrameEx
>   + 12622 27  org.python.python                 0x00000001000b9af5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx
>   + 2197 28  org.python.python              0x00000001000b9c16 PyEval_EvalCode +
>   54 29  org.python.python
>     0x00000001000de50c
>   PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 380 30 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000de76e
>   PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 78 31 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000defe1
>   PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 161 32 
>   org.python.python
>     0x00000001000ee40c Py_Main + 2764 33 
>   org.python.python
>     0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State
>   (64-bit):   rax: 0x000000010113ed88 
>   rbx: 0x000000010058f030  rcx:
>   0x0000000000000000  rdx:
>   0x0000000100592030   rdi:
>   0x0000000000000000  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbp:
>   0x00007fff5fbfccf0  rsp:
>   0x00007fff5fbfcce8    r8:
>   0x0000000000000100   r9:
>   0x0000000010035468  r10:
>   0x000000000000002a  r11:
>   0x0000000100592054   r12:
>   0x0000000000000000  r13:
>   0x0000000000000000  r14:
>   0x000000010058f030  r15:
>   0x00007fff5fbfcf20   rip:
>   0x0000000000000000  rfl:
>   0x0000000000010206  cr2:
>   0x0000000000000000
>
> Binary Images:
>          0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python 2.6.6
>   (2.6.6)
>   <9D90DD3B-6C94-741D-4900-0FDD4139E880>
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>          0x100003000 -        0x10014fff7 +org.python.python 2.6.6,
>   (c) 2004-2008 Python Software
>   Foundation. (2.6.6)
>   
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
>          0x1002e3000 -        0x1002e5ff7 +readline.so ??? (???)
>   
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so
>          0x100440000 -        0x100468ff7 +libreadline.6.1.dylib
>   6.1.0 (compatibility 6.0.0) 
>   /opt/local/lib/libreadline.6.1.dylib
>          0x10047e000 -        0x1004c3fef +libncursesw.5.dylib 5.0.0
>   (compatibility 5.0.0)
>   
>   /opt/local/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib
>          0x1004d2000 -        0x1004fcff7 +libncurses.5.dylib 5.0.0
>   (compatibility 5.0.0)
>   <9829BCEB-0A54-5FA7-788E-0F0593301164>
>   /opt/local/lib/libncurses.5.dylib
>          0x100555000 -        0x10056efff +vigranumpycore.so ???
>   (???)
>   <9B417A36-C0B4-47FC-0D7C-C24E9AFC1A42>
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/vigra/vigranumpycore.so
>          0x100700000 -        0x10073fff7 +libboost_python-mt.dylib
>   ??? (???)
>   <1D14BD86-A204-EBD7-59EE-A733E09C1A96>
>   /opt/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
>          0x101000000 -        0x101110ff7  org.python.python 2.6.1
>   (2.6.1)
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
>       0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???)
>   
>   /usr/lib/dyld
>       0x7fff803e9000 -     0x7fff8049ffff  libobjc.A.dylib
>   227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) 
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>       0x7fff8293e000 -     0x7fff82942ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib
>   315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5>
>   /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
>       0x7fff82c46000 -     0x7fff82e04fff  libicucore.A.dylib
>   40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0E53A4A6-AC06-1B61-2285-248F534EE356>
>   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
>       0x7fff83b44000 -     0x7fff83cb9ff7 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.3
>   (550.29)
>   <48810602-63C3-994D-E563-DD02B16E76E1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>       0x7fff86454000 -     0x7fff864a0fff  libauto.dylib ???
>   (???)
>   <205CE82B-3DE0-4A9D-CEB9-F6A3DDA22ED4>
>   /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
>       0x7fff86b03000 -     0x7fff86b80fef  libstdc++.6.dylib
>   7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C>
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>       0x7fff8752e000 -     0x7fff876eefef  libSystem.B.dylib
>   125.2.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>       0x7fff88245000 -     0x7fff88256ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3
>   (compatibility 1.0.0)
>   
>   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>       0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ???
>   (???)
>   <95E02DD0-ADEA-745B-E7FA-ABA064E4658C>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM
>   MBP61.0057.B0C, 2 processors, Intel
>   Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f16
>   Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M,
>   NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
>   Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD
>   Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB Memory
>   Module: global_name AirPort:
>   spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme
>   (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0
>   (5.10.131.16.1) Bluetooth: Version
>   2.3.7f1, 2 service, 12 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service:
>   AirPort, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA
>   Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02,
>   298,09 GB Serial ATA Device:
>   MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898 USB Device:
>   Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514,
>   0xfa100000 USB Device: Internal Memory
>   Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.),
>   0x8403, 0xfa130000 USB Device: Apple
>   Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac 
>   (Apple Inc.), 0x0237, 0xfa120000 USB
>   Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c 
>   (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000
>   USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host
>   Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.),
>   0x8218, 0xfa113000 USB Device: Hub,
>   0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 USB
>   Device: External HDD, 0x1058  (Western
>   Digital Technologies, Inc.), 0x0705,
>   0xfd130000 USB Device: IR Receiver,
>   0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242,
>   0xfd120000 USB Device: Built-in
>   iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507,
>   0xfd110000

Comment: Have you checked your spam filter? I get a lot of junk emails trying to get me to import vigra :P

Answer (score 0):

Does your `numpy` work well? Did you run its tests? Its installation notes remind of ABI mismatches and right compiler choice; probably a wrong choice might lead to a segfault. The crash happens near `init_module_vigranumpycore`; maybe it's not vigra yet.

Comment: OK, I'll test numpy. Hope I can find the problem. Thank you for the answer.